# STS: Maven fails to load spring-orm dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven

I am using Spring Tool Suite, trying to create an MVC application with Hibernate 4. But Maven fails to load spring-orm dependency. I tried to reinstall STS, and several other methods. Can you help me what could be the problem?

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What's spring.version specified as?

Comment: Can we have the error log ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "maven fails to load" and what is the value of ${spring.version}?

Comment: Reinstalling STS will not fix the broken plugin called m2eclipse.

Comment: I think I found the answer ${spring.version} was not parsed. If I manually write in the version code, it works. Thx david99world.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, ${spring.version} was not parsed. If I manually write in the version code, it works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `${spring.version}`, if you haven't then you need to hard code the version number.